# TweetSharp Search Always Returns Null

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

I am trying to get TweetSharp to search with twitter.  It always returns null.  There is no error or other information.  I setup my consumerkey, consumer secret, access token, and token secret

Here is my code:

```
TwitterService service = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken, tokenSecret);

SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions { Q = "#VeternsDay", Count = 100, Resulttype = TwitterSearchResultType.Recent };
TwitterSearchResult searchedTweets = service.Search(options);
return searchedTweets;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I was playing around C# and Tweetsharp and saw your question and tried to solve it :)

I tried to recreate your example and I got it working! You needed to loop over the searchedTweets.Statuses and get their contents. In this example I got the 100 popular tweets in the #Bahrain hashtag and got those tweets username authors.

```
var service = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions { Q = "#Bahrain", Count = 100, Resulttype = TwitterSearchResultType.Popular};
TwitterSearchResult searchedTweets = service.Search(options);
foreach(var tweet in searchedTweets.Statuses)
{
     MessageBox.Show( tweet.Author.ScreenName);
}
```